# How to prefill docusign template tabs in C# embedded signing?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a template that I have created a custom tab for email that I want to pass a value from my DB in the API call for embedded signing. How can this be accomplished? The below is not working.                                                           example:

```
                "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
                "<templateRoles>" +
                "<templateRole>" +
                "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                "<name>" + recipientName + "</name>" +
                "<roleName>" + templateRole + "</roleName>" +
                "<clientUserId>1</clientUserId>" +  // user-configurable +
                "<tabs>" +
                "<texttabs>" +
                "<texttab>" +
                    "<tablabel>Email</tablabel>" +
                    "<value> " + recipientEmail + "</value>" +
                "</texttab>" +
                "</texttabs>" +
                "</tabs>" +
                "</templateRole>" +
                "</templateRoles>" +
                "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
           .....
           "<tabs>" +
            "<texttabs>" +
               "<text>" +
                "<tablabel>Email</tablabel>" +
                "<value> " + recipientEmail + "</value>" +
               "</text>" +
            "</texttabs>" +
            "</tabs>" +
         .......
```